# Выбор виртуальной машины

Tags: виртуальная-машина

На новой работе приходиться пользоваться виндой :( 
Хочу поставить нормальную виртуалку и накатить linux.
Посоветуйте что-нибудь из личного опыта.

Критерии:

- Минимальная потеря производительности;
- не надо покупать;
- хост-машина: windows, гостевая-машина: linux
- располагаю машинкой с ЦПУ 3,1 Ггц, ОЗУ 4Гб

Пробовал VirtualBox, но xubuntu ели тянет.
Дома юзаю KVM -- очень хорошая вещь, но для винды версии нет.

P.s. Просьба холивар не устраивать и ответы сопровождать комментариями на основе собственного опыта, а не Дяди Васи.

Comment: Пожалуй, из тех, что "не нужно покупать", VirtualBox - самый лучший. Лучше вряд ли есть. У меня тоже Xubuntu 12.04 слегка тормозит, хотя железо весьма мощное. А вот Mint 13 вполне быстро бегает. Даже не знаю почему.

Comment: Я купил Vmware workstation и очень довольный. Он быстрый и очень функциональный. Минуса только два - 1.english 2.платный

Comment: А vmware player чем не угодил? Он вроде бесплатный был?

Comment: Есть же Microsoft Virtual PC. Я придерживаюсь мнения, что разработчики ОС хоста, как никто другой, знают тонкие моменты для реализации данного функционала. Нативные приложения, а не универсальные, всегда работали лучше и показывали соответственно лучшую производительность. Можно конечно завести холивар на эту тему, но думаю не стоит.

Comment: @stck не нашёл информации о том поддерживает ли  Virtual PC гостевую систему с на базе linux.

Comment: @zenith, а что Вы гоняли под Xubuntu и почувствовали что еле тянет? И RAM у виртуалки какой?

--

У меня и не работе и дома VirtualBox. Один комп Core2Duo 2.7Ghz, другой I5-2500 3.3Ghz. На одном xubuntu 12.04 32-bit на другом ubuntu 10.04 64-bit. Обе виртуалки 1GB RAM в одной 1 в другой (ubuntu) 4 CPU.

По моим ощущениям **все работает быстро**. С файловой системой вообще быстрее родной (host) винды. С многозадачностью, конечно, тормозит. "На глаз" не заметно, но тесты на серваках с vmware и RedHat на железе это показали.

--

Короче, для разработки меня VirtualBox вполне устраивает.

Comment: @zenith [Тутор][1] есть, правда староватый и только для того чтобы показать существование данной фичи. Я под виндовой машиной пользовался на работе - вполне устраивало.
[1]:http://arcanecode.com/2008/04/24/installing-ubuntu-804-under-microsoft-virtual-pc-2007/

Comment: [Сравнительная таблица Виртуальных машин][1] - тема давно раскрыта.


  [1]: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_platform_virtual_machines

Comment: @sergiks и эту и другую [таблицу][1] я уже видел. Только это скорее довод разума, чем личный опыт.
[1]: http://http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD

Comment: Таблица в комментарии @zenith, пожалуй, посодержательней.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Извиняюсь если не конкретно по вопросу, но я без особых проблем в xubuntu на виртуалбоксе запускал xubuntu на своем Asus EeePc - раза в 4 слабее описанных характеристик. Мне кажется надо грамотно подобрать swap и размещение файла оси на ЖД и выделение ресурсов для виртуалки - найти ту золотую серединку чтобы винда не перехватывала ресурсы и чтобы виртуалке хватало.

Comment: В общем-то на virtualbox и остановился. Действительно пришлось немного повозится с настройко гостть-машины.

Answer (score 1):

VMWare же есть бесплатная версия. Мне нравится.